# Voltage Doubler capacitance calculation

Tags: voltage, capacitor, simulation, pspice, voltage-doubler

I have an astable multivibrator that produces 5 V square wave input to the push pull and the voltage doubler part of the circuit. Now somehow the simulation works at 0.1 uF capacitors for the voltage doubler, but I do not understand how to select the values for the capacitor when I have an input at 32.3 kHz. My max current load will be 60 mA.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

C3 and C4 are way too small. You will need more requirements for a complete design, but here is a start.

For C4:

\$ I = C \frac{dv}{dt} \$

\$ C = \frac{I \Delta t}{\Delta v} \$

For t = 1/2f (one half the period), I = 60 mA, and a voltage ripple of 50 mV:

C4 = 18 uF, I would round up to 33 uF.

The calculation for C3 is more complicated, let's make it the same as C4 for now and run the simulation.

The circuit has a lot of losses, you won't get anywhere near double the voltage with this design.

When Q4 is ON, C3 charges and C4 discharges into the load. (orange paths)

When Q3 is ON, C3 discharges into C4 and the load. (blue paths)

I am assuming that the transistors are fully on, they may not be. And lowering R5 too much may affect the multivibrator. This is beyond the scope of my answer, I am concentrating on the voltage doubler.

For a higher voltage output, consider MOSFETs and Schottky diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJK6s6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]